# C# Retrieving a specific piece of information from JSON string by using Newtonsoft.json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

JSON string that i retrieved:

```
{
  "trackItemResponse" : {
    "hdr" : {
      "messageType" : "TRACKITEM",
      "messageDateTime" : "2021-04-28T16:32:05+08:00",
      "messageVersion" : "1.0",
      "messageLanguage" : "en"
    },
    "bd" : {
      "shipmentItems" : [ {
        "masterShipmentID" : null,
        "shipmentID" : "MYCGUMY8202104SIN00005",
        "trackingID" : "5021049762931421",
        "orderNumber" : null,
        "handoverID" : null,
        "shippingService" : {
          "productCode" : "PDO",
          "productName" : "Parcel Domestic"
        },
        "consigneeAddress" : {
          "country" : "MY"
        },
        "weight" : "804",
        "dimensionalWeight" : "640",
        "weightUnit" : "G",
        "events" : [ {
          "status" : "77093",
          "description" : "Successfully delivered",
          "dateTime" : "2021-04-06 13:47:56",
          "timezone" : "LT",
          "address" : {
            "city" : "Skudai",
            "postCode" : "81300",
            "state" : "JOHOR",
            "country" : "MY"
          }
        }, {
          "status" : "77090",
          "description" : "Out for Delivery",
          "dateTime" : "2021-04-06 10:51:55",
          "timezone" : "LT",
          "address" : {
            "city" : "Skudai",
            "postCode" : "81300",
            "state" : "JOHOR",
            "country" : "MY"
          }
        }, {
          "status" : "77184",
          "description" : "Processed at delivery facility",
          "dateTime" : "2021-04-06 07:56:07",
          "timezone" : "LT",
          "address" : {
            "city" : "Skudai",
            "postCode" : "81300",
            "state" : "Johor",
            "country" : "MY"
          }
        }, {
          "status" : "77178",
          "description" : "Arrived at facility",
          "dateTime" : "2021-04-06 07:30:26",
          "timezone" : "LT",
          "address" : {
            "city" : "Skudai",
            "postCode" : "81300",
            "state" : "Johor",
            "country" : "MY"
          }
        }, {
          "status" : "77169",
          "description" : "Departed from facility",
          "dateTime" : "2021-04-06 05:22:02",
          "timezone" : "LT",
          "address" : {
            "city" : "Kuala Lumpur Hub",
            "postCode" : "47100",
            "state" : "Kuala Lumpur",
            "country" : "MY"
          }
        }, {
          "status" : "77027",
          "description" : "Sorted to delivery facility",
          "dateTime" : "2021-04-05 21:00:05",
          "timezone" : "LT",
          "address" : {
            "city" : "Kuala Lumpur Hub",
            "postCode" : "47100",
            "state" : "Kuala Lumpur",
            "country" : "MY"
          }
        }, {
          "status" : "77015",
          "description" : "Processed at facility",
          "dateTime" : "2021-04-05 20:59:04",
          "timezone" : "LT",
          "address" : {
            "city" : "Kuala Lumpur Hub",
            "postCode" : "47100",
            "state" : "Kuala Lumpur",
            "country" : "MY"
          }
        }, {
          "status" : "71005",
          "description" : "DATA SUBMITTED",
          "dateTime" : "2021-04-02 15:44:40",
          "timezone" : "Malaysia",
          "address" : {
            "city" : "SEPANG, SELANGOR",
            "postCode" : "43900",
            "state" : "SEL",
            "country" : "MY"
          }
        } ]
      } ],
      "responseStatus" : {
        "code" : "200",
        "message" : "SUCCESS",
        "messageDetails" : [ {
          "messageDetail" : "1 tracking reference(s) tracked, 1 tracking reference(s) found."
        } ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output that i wanted:

```
5021049762931421 //trackingID
```

Method_1 that i've tried:

```
HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
     string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
     Console.WriteLine(result);
     dynamic data = JObject.Parse(result);
     Console.WriteLine(data.trackItemResponse.bd.shipmentItems.trackingID);
}
```

Output:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' does not contain a definition for 'trackingID''
```

Method_2 that i've tried:

```
HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
     var trckID = JObject.Parse(result)["trackItemResponse"]["bd"]["shipmentItems"].Select(x => (string)x["trackingID"]).ToList();
     Console.WriteLine("Below is json data");
     Console.WriteLine(trckID);
     Console.WriteLine("Until here la");
}
```

Output_2:

```
Below is json data
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
Until here la
```

Method_3 that i've tried:

```
HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
     string jsonData = JObject.Parse(result)["trackItemResponse"]["bd"]["shipmentItems"]["trackingID"].ToString();
     Console.WriteLine("Below is json data");
     Console.WriteLine(jsonData);
     Console.WriteLine("Until here la");
}
```

Output_3:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "trackingID". Int32 array index expected.'
```

Is there any other methods that could work? Thank you.

Post that i've refered

[Convert string to int C#](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/convert-string-to-int)

[C# cast from string to int/int32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279353/c-sharp-casting-from-string-to-int-or-int32-possible)

[Make newtonsoft.json convert default to int32 rather than int64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919465/make-newtonsoft-jsonconvert-default-to-int32-rather-than-int64)

[C# extract json array with newtonsoft.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928029/c-sharp-extract-json-array-of-objects-using-with-newtonsoft-json)

Thank you for your kind assistance!

Comment: Can you decide if you want `shipmentID` or `trackingID` please and update the question as appropriate.

Comment: `shipmentItems` is an array, which is the source of your issue. Perhaps all you need is `shipmentItems[0]` if there will always be a single item.

Comment: @Jamiec waht i wanted trackingID, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for

```
var result = JObject.Parse(result)["trackItemResponse"]["bd"]["shipmentItems"][0]["trackingID"].ToString();
```

But keep in mind that `shipmentItems` is a list, so could contain multiple items.
This code only checks the first in that list.

Answer (score 1):

[SelectToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) is what you are looking for:

```cs
var semiParsedJson = JObject.Parse(json);
var trackingId = semiParsedJson
    .SelectToken("trackItemResponse.bd.shipmentItems[0].trackingID");
```

Please bear in mind that this solution assumes that the first object in the `shipmentItems` collection contains the required information.

If it is not present then `trackingId` will be `null`.

---

If you have multiple objects inside the `shipmentItems` and you are interested about all of the `trackingId` values then you have to use `SelectTokens`

```cs
var semiParsedJson = JObject.Parse(json);
var trackingIds = semiParsedJson
    .SelectTokens("trackItemResponse.bd.shipmentItems[*].trackingID");
```

Please note that the indexer operator now receives a `*` wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, you are almost there.
Since the object "data.trackItemResponse.bd.shipmentItems" is an array, you need to access the "trackingID" after selecting the index.

Your code should be:

```
HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
     string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
     Console.WriteLine(result);
     dynamic data = JObject.Parse(result);
     
     //Test this 
     var trackingID = data.trackItemResponse.bd.shipmentItems[0].trackingID;
     Console.WriteLine(data.trackItemResponse.bd.shipmentItems[0].trackingID);
}
```